# query counts of 5 different data extension fields

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql

We are looking to query counts of subscribers that unsubscribed from 5 separate fields (or unsubscribe buckets) in our master data set within the past day.

We need to ultimately see counts of how many unsubscribed from each field via FALSE or 0 Records

Here is the query that fails:

Query 1:

```
SELECT distinct 
s.SubscriberID 
FROM _Sent s WHERE s.EventDate > dateadd(day,-1,getdate())
```

Updated Query 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
nd.SubscriberId
, md.DEA
, md.DEB
, md.DEC
, md.DED
, md.DEE
, md.DEF 
FROM Master_dataset md 
join new_dataset nd
ON nd.SubscriberID = md.email 
where md.DEA = 0 
OR md.DEB = 0 
OR md.DEC = 0 
OR md.DED = 0 
OR md.DEE= 0 
OR md.DEF = 0
```

Comment: Which query fails? 1 or 2? What's the error message?

Comment: got them both to run yet the first is the only one that populates. So we see all of the subscriber keys yet no false/0 values for each field in the second query...

Comment: updated Query 1:

SELECT distinct s.SubscriberID

FROM _Sent s 

WHERE s.EventDate > dateadd(day,-1,getdate())

Updated Query 2:

SELECT DISTINCT nd.SubscriberId, md.DEA, md.DEB, md.DEC, md.DED, 
md.DEE, md.DEF

FROM Master_dataset md

join new_dataset nd ON nd.SubscriberID = md.email

where md.DEA = 0 

OR md.DEB = 0

OR md.DEC = 0 

OR md.DED = 0
 
OR md.DEE= 0

OR md.DEF = 0